# Ignore case sensitivity - laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, case-sensitive

Let say i have following

```
$quizresult = Quizresult::findOrFail($id);
```

My Modal class file name is  **QuizResult.php**

I am working on windows server on localhost which automatically ignores case sensitivity.
No matter whether it is Quizresult or QuizResult

When i upload it to linux server it is throwing error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Quizresult' not found
```

**Is there any tricks in laravel to ignore case sensitivity?**

Comment: Even though the files are maybe not case sensitive, the framework can be.if your PHP class name is QuizResult then you should use that exact one.

Comment: The PSR autoloaders are case-sensitive. Unless you create a different autoloader, yo won't be able to do anything about his.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding files is case-insensitive on Windows, but is case-sensitive on Unix systems. It is the same reason that a "wrong" written URL can be found on Windows, but not on Unix.

Whenever you work with filenames/paths for internet applications, you should write your code case sensitive, to stay compatible with other systems.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to remove the case sensitivity in PHP on Linux. It is on a Laravel thing though, it is related to the implementation of the system itself.

I would recommend to use the same version of the system and any software (apache, php...) on all your environments...